# How to detect object is perpendicular to camera optical axis?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect whether object is perpendicular to optical axis.[image]

Sample input will be an image that has and object (cylinder shape similar to a bottle) in it and a mostly plain background.

Output will be a boolean determining whether that object is perpendicular to camera axis. This does not require to have much accuracy.

For example following image is not perpendicular to camera axis.

[image]

Following image is not perpendicular too because camera angle is little bit from above

[image]

Next image is perpendicular and in the correct position

[image]

Is is possible to do this in steps using OpenCV. If so what are are the steps (High-level overview is enough)

Comment: Your question is too broad. Add more details i.e code, sample input, current result, expected result etc.

Comment: @zindarod I did add some example images. Hope things are little bit clear now.

Comment: no there is not. this is too special. think of OpenCV as a toolbox. you can build a house with a tool box but you won't find a house-builder tool if you know what I mean...

Comment: **1)** convert image to gray, threshold and find contours **2)** using `minAreaRect()` find the (rotated) bounding box of the contours **3)** `minAreaRect` also returns the rotation angle. If you don't want to rely on this given angle, find slope of the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: @Piglet Yes. My bad asking for a single algorithm. What I really need is to know if there are any steps I can follow in opencv toolkit to archive something like this.

Comment: yes but I won't explain that to you. it would take too much time. the only simple way you can go, given your non-existent experience is template matching.  have a reference image of a perpendicular view and then check wether it looks like that or not.

Comment: @Piglet Thanks I'll try that. Could you think of a quick high level overview of steps to follow. Just ignore my request if that takes too much time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zindarod I'll try this in python and post results.